# tikzpicture does not fit in the document

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have a code, where I use some scopes to draw some 3D-figures. 
But the output does not fit in the standalone-document. 
`\hbox{*}` and `\vbox{*}` does not help.

What do I have to do?

[image]

Should look like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\def\a{1}
\def\h{0.2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hbox{\vbox{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
very thin,
%line cap=round,
x={(1,0,0)}, z={(0,1,0)}, y={(0.5,0.5)}, 
every label/.style={text=black!1},
]

\coordinate[label=below:A] (A1) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:B] (B1) at (\a,0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:C] (C1) at (\a,\a,0);
\coordinate[label=below:D] (D1) at (0,\a,0);
\coordinate[label=below:A] (A2) at (0,0,\h);
\coordinate[label=below:B] (B2) at (\a,0,\h);
\coordinate[label=below:C] (C2) at (\a,\a,\h);
\coordinate[label=below:D] (D2) at (0,\a,\h);

%% straight %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\foreach \n in {0,...,9}{%%
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(0,0,\n*\h)}}]
\draw[] (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1); 

\ifnum\n=9 \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2) --cycle; 
\else \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2);  \fi
\foreach \P in {A,B,C} \draw[] (\P1) -- (\P2);
\end{scope}
}%%

%% skew  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(12*\h+\a,0,0)}}]
\foreach \n in {0,...,9}{%%
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={shift={(-\n*\h,0,\n*\h)}}]
\draw[] (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1); 

\ifnum\n=9 \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2) --cycle; 
\else \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2);  \fi
\foreach \P in {A,B,C}{  \draw[] (\P1) -- (\P2);  }
\draw[fill=white] (B1) -- (C1) -- (C2) -- (B2) --cycle;
\end{scope}
}%%
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would avoid `transform canvas` for everything where any other methods can be used. There is nothing special here that justify the usage.

Comment: `transform canvas` interacts very badly with the bounding box, which is what is failing here. There should be a better way, but for example you you add an invisible path like `\path (0,0) rectangle (4,4);` you'll have your full picture (not optimal, I know)

Comment: A quick hack would be to manually set the bounding box. Put `\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (5,5);` at end of code with suitable coordinates.

Comment: Aha... phew, then I have to write `[shift={(0,0,\n*\h)}]`  at each coordinate `([...]A1)`, I think.

Comment: Just to add a reference: last paragraph in https://tikz.dev/base-transformations#sec-108.3

Comment: @cis No you don't ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to avoid `transform canvas` and adding the transformation each time you use a coordinate.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707241/ addaswyd o gwestiwn cis: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/707215/
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
    very thin,
    x={(1,0,0)}, z={(0,1,0)}, y={(0.5,0.5)}, 
  ]
  \def\a{1}
  \def\h{0.2}
  \def\makecoords{%
    \coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B1) at (\a,0,0);
    \coordinate (C1) at (\a,\a,0);
    \coordinate (D1) at (0,\a,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (0,0,\h);
    \coordinate (B2) at (\a,0,\h);
    \coordinate (C2) at (\a,\a,\h);
    \coordinate (D2) at (0,\a,\h);}
  %% straight %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \foreach \n in {0,...,9}{%%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,\n*\h)}]
      \makecoords
      \draw (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1);
      \ifnum\n=9 \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2) -- cycle; 
      \else \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2);  \fi
      \foreach \P in {A,B,C} \draw[] (\P1) -- (\P2);
    \end{scope}
  }  
  %% skew  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \begin{scope}[shift={(12*\h+\a,0,0)}]
    \foreach \n in {0,...,9}{%%
      \begin{scope}[shift={(-\n*\h,0,\n*\h)}]
        \makecoords
        \draw[] (A1) -- (B1) -- (C1); 
        \ifnum\n=9 \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2) --cycle; 
        \else \draw[fill=white] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2);  \fi
        \foreach \P in {A,B,C}{  \draw[] (\P1) -- (\P2);  }
        \draw[fill=white] (B1) -- (C1) -- (C2) -- (B2) --cycle;
      \end{scope}
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacked and stepped]

I wasn't sure what the `\vbox` in an `\hbox` was for, so I removed it as it seemed to serve no function.